# How to delete first line of XML file using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have small requirement, I'm getting JSON data through xslt. But I'm, getting xml tag line as well. here I need to remove first line of my code
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, using jQuery. Could you please share me your ideas,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

      [{"name":"testtest",
      "desc":" (test test)",
       "values" : [ {
                "from" : " /Date(10/01/2015 09:00:00)/",
         "to" : " /Date(12/01/2015 09:00:00)/",
         "label" : "test" 
}]
}]
```

Comment: The correct solution would be to fix your xslt.

Comment: `I'm getting JSON data through xslt`... why?

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions of course like this :

```
yourText.value = yourText.value.replace("/\<\?xml(.+?)\?\>/g", "")
```